# Strong law of large numbers implications

Tags: probability-theory, asymptotics, law-of-large-numbers

Let $S_n$ be the sum of i.i.d. components $X_i$ with $P(X_i= 0) = P(X_i = 1) = 1/2$. Then, according to the strong law of large numbers we have that $$ \frac{S_n}{n} \to 1/2 \quad a.s.$$
Can I follow that: Let $\epsilon > 0$. There exists a $n_0$ such that for all $n \geq n_0$: $$ \frac{n}{2} - \epsilon < S_n < \frac{n}{2} + \epsilon \quad a.s. \ $$ Or am I interpreting the SLLN incorrectly? Or, can I only infer a statement like $$ 
 \frac{n}{4} < S_n < \frac{3n}{4} \quad a.s. \quad ?$$

Comment: Note that $\mathbb{P}(S_n=n)=2^{-n}$ is non-zero in this case. So none of your statements can be true.

Comment: @SangchulLee Thanks! Would you know, whether there is a way to get a result like the second one? For instance, it makes sense that $r^{S_n} \to 0$, if $r < 1$, and $r^{S_n} \to \infty$, if $r >1$. To prove it, I thought about the above statement.

Comment: It is almost hopeless to create any non-trivial statement of the form $$\mathbb{P}(\text{some statement about $S_n$})=1\text{ holds eventually}$$ due to outliers. However, often this is not what you really need, especially when you are interested in path-wise behaviors (I.e., how $n\mapsto S_n$ behaves). Instead, we have much better luck in finding statements of the form $$\mathbb{P}(\text{some statement about $S_n$ holds eventually})=1.$$ For instance, SLLN shows that, for each $\epsilon > 0$, $$(\tfrac{1}{2}-\epsilon)n<S_n<(\tfrac{1}{2}+\epsilon)n\text{ holds eventually}\quad\text{a.s.}$$

Comment: @SangchulLee In this thread of mathoverflow https://mathoverflow.net/questions/363390/asymptotic-behavior-of-a-random-geometric-sum I found in the first answer the following statement: If $0 < r < 1$, then by the strong law of large numbers, there is a positive inter-valued random variable $N$ such that $S_k > k/4$ a.s. and hence, $r^{S_k} \leq r^{k/4}$ a.s. for all $k \geq N$. Now I don't understand this conclusion by the author. Do you know?

Comment: By SLLN, we know that $S_n>n/4$ will hold if $k$ is sufficiently large. But how large $n$ should be? A crucial observation is that it will depend on the sample that you observe. So, the threshold $N$ at which this inequality begins to hold are not a constant, but rather a function of samples. This is essentially what is meant by that implication. And even though $N$ is not the same for different samples, that does not hinder you from investigating the pointwise limit of $r^{S_n}$.

Answer (score 1):

The convergence delivered by the SLLN is point-wise, not uniform.    The central limit theorem tells us that deviations of $S_n$ from $n/2$ are typically of size $\pm\sqrt n$, so your first formula asks for the impossible. The law of the iterated logarithm tells us that   with probability $1$ we have

$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{S_n-n/2}{\sqrt{n\log\log n}}=1$$
and
$$\liminf_{n\to\infty}\frac{S_n-n/2}{\sqrt{n\log\log n}}=-1.$$
This shows your first formula cannot hold, and gives a way to prove your second.